# Dark spots in 3D model in Vuforia for Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am developing a AR app for Windows in Vuforia for Unity3D, and all of my models look great except for one. It renders with dark patches and it gets worst the further apart you take the camera.

It looks like this:

[image]

The model in question is a .obj file with a PNG texture file. All models are the same but they look perfect, this is the only one showing this flaw. Look at this example:

[image]

Is this a known issue in Vuforia or Unity3D?

Versions:

- Unity 5.3.4f1 (32-bit)
- Vuforia for Unity 5.5.9
- Windows 10

Comment: No one is in possession of your 3D model so try to eliminate which 3D application is the problem by exporting the 3D model to a new scene without Vuforia plugin. If the problem is still there then 3D model is the problem..